# Is it possible to transform square-meters into liters?

Tags: geometry, area

> The external surface area (excluding the base) of a wine barrel in the shape of a cylinder requires painting. The diameter of the barrel is 5m and the height is 2m. Calculate the amount of paint needed for each barrel correct to one decimal place.

My solution:

$$\text{Surface area}=2 \pi r h+\pi r^2 =  
2\pi 2.5\cdot 2+\pi 2.5^2=51.1m^2$$

Is it possible to transform the area in $m^2$ into liters of paint? or do I just leave it in $m^2$?

Comment: Your question is incomplete.

Comment: You need to say how much paint you use for $1m^2$, or how thick is the layer of paint

Comment: @Andrei it is not specified in the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation of the area is correct.  To get the volume of paint you will use, you need to multiply it by the thickness of the paint, which is not specified.  Often it will say on the can how many $m^2$ you can cover with one liter.  Without that information you can't say how much paint is required.

Comment: One could just say it's the calculated area times the thickness. Given the way the problem is phrased, that seems sufficient.